# How to send emails with a Return Path in .net 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, system.net.mail, email-bounces, return-path

Can any one guide me on how i can send emails with a return path in ASP.net 3.5 / C# 3.5. I know this was possible few years back but now due to spoofing issues this is not possible. I have been looking on internet but no use. I want the emails if bounced, should reach my bounce mail box, which could be like Bounce@mydomain.com.

Please guide. Really stuck ...

Best regards,
Haroon

Answer (score 2):

I did a check on systemnetmail.com and found that you are not able to.

> According to the RFCs, the Return-Path can only be added by the recieving server. If an exisiting Return-Path header is found, it is to be removed, or not obeyed.
>
> So, adding a Return-Path header won't work.

[Source](http://www.systemnetmail.com/forums/forum_viewpost.aspx?forum=3&post=1070)

Comment: Hi @Mike is there any other way of doing this? any workaround for this?

Comment: Nope, not unless you can build a hybrid time machine / dodge ball canon and re-write the RFCs yourself.

The simple solution could be to send out the emails using this format name+bounce@domain.com then set up a filter in your mail client to catch the bounced e-mails.  The way e-mail servers work they will ignore anything after that + sign.  So the e-mail will get routed to your account.  Also you will probably want to set a display name in the header so the original recipients won't see name+bounce@domain.com they'll see something like Haroon or Haroon@domain.com